# Rationalize and evaluate when $h=0: \frac{\sqrt{16+h}-4}{h}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Rationalize and evaluate when $h=0: \frac{\sqrt{16+h}-4}{h}$

I know how to rationalize when there is a radical in the denominator (multiply by conjugate) but how do I rationalize when there is no radical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{16+h}-4}{h} 
&= 
\frac{\sqrt{16+h}-4}{h}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt {16+h}+4}{\sqrt {16+h}+4}\right) 
=\dotsb\\\\\dotsb&= 
\frac{(16+h)-16}{h(\sqrt {16+h}+4)}
= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt {16+h}+4}
\end{align}$$